# VBA query: using clipboard data to filter

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using multiple worksheets in Excel to create a database of candidates undergoing some technical training.  Each time a candidate is added to the 'database' they are assigned a unique number, for example "2015-0001".  When they call to pay their deposit, I'm using a data input table for the telephone operator to note down the details, and it looks up the unique number for the candidate.  I then want to filter the main database for the candidate by their number and paste in the confirmed details of the deposit.

My query is this: how do I write the code that copies the candidate number data from the cell on worksheet 1 and then uses that data (irrespective of its value) to filter worksheet 2?

I'm new to macros and have been using "record macro" to generate code which I then edit and learn as I go.  So, apologies if this looks extremely clunky.  Using record, the filter command simply takes the example text I'm using (in this case 2015-0011), not replacing it with the revised value when the Deposit input table is changed and the macro is run.  Am I right to think that I need to use a String?

Thanks in advance.  RLC

```
Sub Confirm_Deposit()
'
' Confirm_Deposit Macro
'


'
    Sheets("Take Deposit").Select
    Range("C5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CIP Candidates").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$AK$2507").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "2015-0011"                     <---------------- ISSUE
    Sheets("Take Deposit").Select
    Range("C6:C8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CIP Candidates").Select
    Range("A6").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Offset(0, 20).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Application.Run _
        "'CIP Spreadsheet RLC (with Macros).xlsm'!ThisWorkbook.Clear_Filters"


etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been a while but will this do the trick?

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$AK$2507").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    Sheets("Take Deposit").Cells(5,3).Value
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$AK$2507").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    Sheets("Take Deposit").Range("C5").Value
```

theres no need to select and copy the value. You can just reference the Cells Value.

Comment: Thanks Florian, that has worked a treat, and it slots nicely into my existing code. Regards, RLC

Comment: You are welcome. As PJ suggested you should consider learning the whole thing though recording and editing Macros is a good way to get to know the object model. I strongly recommend a real book or e book. I myself learned it from 'Excel VBA' (version 2000 ... as i said its been a while =) ) from Microsoft Press. There you can find plenty usefull hints, tutorials, examples and exercises. I learned Excel VBA in like 3 weeks with 2 hours a day pretty much to its depths.

Comment: *Off to bookstore*Thanks @Florian.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach that is less "Macro" based and more just simple cell manipulation using loops.  It's very flexible.  See what you think of the idea, then we can modify to your specific needs.

The part of this code that I would change immediately is selecting where the lookup value comes from.  In this example, since I don't know your specifics, I saw you are using "C5" in the example above.

```
Sub Confirm_Deposit()

Dim source As String
Dim target As String
Dim lookupVal As String
Dim row As Long
Dim searchRow As Long

    source = "Take Deposit"         'In case you have similar projects, you can just replace these lines.
    target = "CIP Candidates"

    lastSourceRow = Sheets(source).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lastTargetRow = Sheets(target).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lastTargetCol = Sheets(target).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    lookupVal = TextBox1.Text       'Set the lookupVal from whatever source you choose.  I like ComboBoxes when I can.
    For searchRow = 2 To lastSourceRow
        If Sheets(source).Cells(searchRow, 3).Text = lookupVal Then    'Searching through Source Sheet on Col "C"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next searchRow
    'This way, at the end of the search, you have the row number of the original source to be copied, instead of hard coding.

    For row = 6 To lastTargetRow        'Loop through the Target Sheet

        If Sheets(target).Cells(row, 3).Text = lookupVal Then           'Compare lookupVal to the Range being looped.
            For col = 2 To lastTargetCol
                Sheets(target).Cells(row, 3) = Sheets(source).Cells(searchRow, col)  'Copies contents from Row 5 of source sheet.
            Next col
        End If
    Next row

End Sub
```

EDIT:  Made lookup Row dynamic instead of hard coded to row 5

Comment: Cool, thanks for your help PJ.  It's much appreciated.  Because this is such a different approach I'm going to take it offline and work through it.  If there are any good "VBA for Dummies" resources online that you know of, I'd be most keen to hear them!  Regards, RLC.

Comment: Most languages are similar, and the syntax changes.  But the concepts are going to remain.  VBA for Excel is fun because the excel sheet is just a 2D grid, that is easy to increment through by row number or column number.  
Check out MicrosoftVirtualAcademy for great videos, or LearnVisualStudio.Net.  I'm sure you will pick up plenty from those.

Comment: MVA looks like a useful resource over many different software packages, I wasn't aware of it before.  Bookmarked!  Thanks @PJRosenburg.